# ng-change is not working for this code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My Html

```
 <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-change="ChangeHistogramDayCount(1)">
                                <option value="7">Last 7 days</option>
                                <option value="15">Last 15 days</option>
                                <option value="30">Last 30 days</option>
                                <option value="0">Default</option>
                                </select>
```

my java script

```
 $scope.ChangeHistogramDayCount = function(dayCount) {

            $scope.HistoGramDayCount = dayCount;

        };
```

My error data

i am getting a complile error in angularjs file

**I dont want to create models for options, all options are hard coded in  option tag  so how i can made an event when selection changed using angular**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let AngularJS tracking changes by itslef : Use ng-model for databinding between your option value and "HistoryGramDayCount"

More info here : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: changed and its working  ng-model="HistoGramDayCount"